# how do i output a variable from js for html

Tags: javascript, html

Please I want to output a variable from js to an html tag so i can see the results in a specific place on my page. here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doMath()
{
    // Capture the entered values of two input boxes
    var my_input1 = document.getElementById('my_input1').value;
    var my_input2 = document.getElementById('my_input2').value;
    var my_input3 = document.getElementById("my_input3").value;
    var my_input4 = document.getElementById("my_input4").value;
        //alert(form.elements["my_input2"].value);
    //var my_input3 = document.getElementById('my_input3').value;

    // Add them together and display
    var sum = parseInt(my_input1) / parseInt(my_input2) *     parseInt(my_input3) * parseInt(my_input4);
    document.write(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us say you want to display the response in a div with id `sum`

```
<div id="sum"></div>
```

To do so, update

```
document.write(sum);
```

to

```
document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
```

Comment: @KofYeb - Great it worked for you. You can always mark the answer as accepted for future reference.

Comment: Okay. how do i pass that to an input field like this `<div id="sum"></div>` will now be `<input type="text" name="PayableAmount" class="form-control" id="sum" value=""/>` i want to know if its possible like that? and how do i do  it the proper way. thanks and how do i accept answer? thanks

Comment: Update the code to `document.getElementById("sum").value =  sum;`

Comment: like this `<input type="text" name="PayableAmount" class="form-control" document.getElementById("sum").value = sum; />` i just tried this but its not workning

Comment: No no. Not like this. Your html will be `<input type="text" name="PayableAmount" class="form-control" id="sum" value=""/>` only. The script will change. In place `document.write(sum);` it will be `document.getElementById("sum").value = sum;`